# Turn function that finds all permutations of string into generator

Tags: python, generator

I have the following function in order to find all the permutations of a string that works correctly:

```
def permute_string(str):
    if len(str) == 0:
        return ['']
    prev_list = permute_string(str[1:len(str)])
    next_list = []
    for i in range(0,len(prev_list)):
        for j in range(0,len(str)):
            new_str = prev_list[i][0:j]+str[0]+prev_list[i][j:len(str)-1]
            if new_str not in next_list:
                next_list.append(new_str)
    return next_list
```

I would like to turn it into a function that return me a generator in order that when I do:

```
gen = permute_string("abc")
print(next(gen))
```

I'll get "abc".
I've tried to add a yield statement after appending `new_str` to the my `next_list` but it doesn't work (i.e. I get the following message: TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len(), which is kind of normal)

Comment: Why are you iterating unpythonically in the first place?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "unpythonically", what should I do in order to improve it ?

Comment: Iterate the elements of `prev_list` directly, instead of using indices.

Comment: Btw, what's your reason for wanting a generator?